# How to check a hide an element inside element on click using jquery(not duplicate)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` with an `i` tag:

```
<div class="accordion-heading datalist" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#@i.Id">div
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down table-middle" aria-hidden="true">i tag</i>
</div>
```

On first click of the `div` the `i` tag should disappear, on next click of the `div` the `i` tag should appear again. How can I do that?

Comment: Post the code you tried that doesn't work.

Comment: its just nee to know i have a div and a i tag inside my div...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `toggle()` to achieve that:

```
$('.accordion-heading').click(function() {
    $(this).find('i').toggle();
});
```

Note that depending on your styling rules, it may be hard and/or impossible to click the `div` element with the `i` hidden as it will have no height. To fix that you can set a `min-height` rule on the `div`, or put a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) in it.

> I want to switch between `display: none` and `display: tablecell`

In this case you have to manage the `display` value yourself, like this:

```
$('.accordion-heading').click(function() {
    $(this).find('i').css('display', function(i, d) {
        return d == 'none' ? 'tablecell' : 'none';
    })
});
```

Comment: what does toggle do? hiding element?

Comment: It hides/shows the element depending on its current state: http://api.jquery.com/toggle

Comment: the problem is it will switch between display: none and display:block, but i want to switch between display :none and display:tablecell

Comment: you are awesome... can you explain what that function do inside .css(),  and why it need two parametre?

Comment: You should check out the jQuery docs. They're very helpful: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function

Answer (score 0):

use jquery `toggle()`. 
check this 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkcojrjx/)

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery:

```
var accordion = document.querySelector('.accordion-heading');
accordion.addEventListener('click', toggleTag);

function toggleTag() {
  var tagToToggle = accordion.querySelector('i');

  if (!tagToToggle.classList.contains('active')) {
    tagToToggle.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    tagToToggle.classList.remove('active');
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
i {
  display: none;
}

i.active {
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `toggleClass()` method but u create a `css` class for jquery function. its most customizeable

> .display-none{display:none;}    `or`
>
> .display-none{opacity:0;transition:1s solid ease;}

```
$('.accordion-heading').on('click',function() {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('display-none');
});
```

[Click-Here to view example -jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wimufuqudu/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Please check the Link Priya